# Enabling compression on AWS EC2 Instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache, amazon-ec2, compression, gzip

I have a PHP web application running on an AWS EC2 instance (Apache server) and it currently uses no compression. I know this can be easily done by modifying the `.htaccess` file to tell the web server to compress the files, what I need help with is understanding what to put in the file. I've done some research and found two popular different ways, the first is:

```
<ifModule mod_gzip.c>
mod_gzip_on Yes
mod_gzip_dechunk Yes
mod_gzip_item_include file .(html?|txt|css|js|php|pl)$
mod_gzip_item_include handler ^cgi-script$
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/.*
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/x-javascript.*
mod_gzip_item_exclude mime ^image/.*
mod_gzip_item_exclude rspheader ^Content-Encoding:.*gzip.*
</ifModule>
```

and the second is

```
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>

    # Force compression for mangled headers.
    # http://developer.yahoo.com/blogs/ydn/posts/2010/12/pushing-beyond-gzipping
    <IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
        <IfModule mod_headers.c>
            SetEnvIfNoCase ^(Accept-EncodXng|X-cept-Encoding|X{15}|~{15}|-{15})$ ^((gzip|deflate)\s*,?\s*)+|[X~-]{4,13}$ HAVE_Accept-Encoding
            RequestHeader append Accept-Encoding "gzip,deflate" env=HAVE_Accept-Encoding
        </IfModule>
    </IfModule>

    # Compress all output labeled with one of the following MIME-types
    # (for Apache versions below 2.3.7, you don't need to enable `mod_filter`
    #  and can remove the `<IfModule mod_filter.c>` and `</IfModule>` lines
    #  as `AddOutputFilterByType` is still in the core directives).
    <IfModule mod_filter.c>
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/atom+xml \
                                      application/javascript \
                                      application/json \
                                      application/ld+json \
                                      application/rss+xml \
                                      application/vnd.ms-fontobject \
                                      application/x-font-ttf \
                                      application/x-web-app-manifest+json \
                                      application/xhtml+xml \
                                      application/xml \
                                      font/opentype \
                                      image/svg+xml \
                                      image/x-icon \
                                      text/css \
                                      text/html \
                                      text/plain \
                                      text/x-component \
                                      text/xml
    </IfModule>

</IfModule>
```

They both seem to be generally doing the same thing where you specify what type of files and headers are compressed, but I'm confused on what I should actually use.

Also, I would like to understand what each line actually means, some are self explantory but others are not. Is there documentation anywhere so I can understand each and every line of what I'm putting in my `.htaccess` file?

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand `mod_deflate` is Apaches official implementation or compression, whereas `mod_gzip` is handled by a third party.

You can find the [comprehensive documentation for mod_deflate](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_deflate.html) on Apaches official documentation. I was not able to find an official set of documentation for `mod_gzip` so I cannot comment on that.

Personally I would go with `mod_defalte` over `mod_gzip` primarily because it appears to be actively maintained by the Apache foundation, whereas `mod_gzip` is maintained by a third party.